# accessing c# code in razor view @{<text> block

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I apologize if my terminology is not correct.  I just got on a project that uses Javascript and asp.net.  I'm not really familiar with both and am trying to implement some simple features or fix bugs.  Currently the razor view looks like:

```
@{
    string rootUrl = Url.Action(MVC.Files.Files(Model.Id, null));
    Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Scripts(wa => wa.AddSharedGroup(@Url.AssetName(AssetGroups.FileBrowser))
                                                     .AddSharedGroup(@Url.AssetName(AssetGroups.SinglePageApps)))
    .OnDocumentReady(
    @<text>
        window.fileBrowser = fileBrowser('ls', 'file_breadcrumb', '@Model.Path', '@rootUrl');

         var runLink = "@Url.Action(MVC.Runs.Run(Model.Id, Model.ExperimentName.ToLegalUrl()))";

         // checking for the model
         if (@((Model.HasSettings.ToString().ToValue()) == true)) {
console.log("true");
         }
         else {
console.log("false");
}

         window.leftNav = new NavView({
            el: "#navview",
            collection: new NavItems(),
            items: [
```

My model for the page, has a property HasSettings.  Based on HasSettings, I want to populate the `items` array at the bottom fo the code with certain items.  I can't figure out the syntax for this.

I originally started with

`if ('@Model.HasSettings') {`

and have been trying different forms, but I'm really not sure what the syntax is to check it so I can populate my items array.  I know if I look at Model.HasSettings outside of this @ block, it evaluates to True or False.  And then in the console when I run the page, it says True or False is undefined.

My first question is what is the correct syntax?

My second question is, should I just copy and paste the entire block

```
window.leftNav = new NavView({
            el: "#navview",
            collection: new NavItems(),
            items: [
```

into each if/else statement with only the items array being different.  Or is there a cleaner way to do that?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that the case of a boolean value in JS is different than c# when calling ToString() - (uppercase in c#, lower in JS), e.g. "True" versus "true".

Comment: @TimMedora Ya I am starting to realize that.  That was another problem I ran into and wasn't sure what the proper way to do this is :-\.

Comment: Calling `ToLower()` on the c# value will fix that problem.

Comment: @TimMedora  If I change it to if `(@Model.HasRunSettings.ToString() == true)`, I still get True is not defined.  Is there something else it could be?

Comment: Use `if(@Model.HasRunSettings.ToString().ToLower() == true)` to get rid of that particular error.

Comment: He does not need "== true" there.

Comment: @Igor - true, but I don't believe that's the problem, and ultimately I would suggest using `===` not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.leftNav = new NavView({
  el: "#navview",
  collection: new NavItems(),
  items: [
@foreach(Setting item in Model.Settings){
    .... output items as javascript objects here
}
  ]});
```